# Оптимизация паралакса

Tags: javascript, html, css, оптимизация

Как лучше, создать див с фоном и менять его позицию с помощью left, top? Или margin? Или перезаписывать с помощью js background-position?

И да, где можно вычитать такие "тонкости" по поводу производительности?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое правило, по крайней мере у меня, если есть возможность сделать что-то без js - надо делать без js.

Но если вы говорить о паралакс-эффекте, то вряд ли получиться обойтись одним css и позиционированием бэкграунда.

Comment: Не очень хорошее правило